# Moving files modified after a specific date

Tags: bash, mv

How do you move files modified after a specific date (say 7 days for example) to another directory? I clumsily tried sending the output of

```
ls -t | head -n XX
```

But learnt recently that it isn't a good idea to parse ls.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are correct that it is best to avoid parsing `ls`.  The solution below uses `find`.  It will, by contrast, work with even the most difficult file names.

To move all files in the current directory modified less than 7 days ago to `/destination/path`, use:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mtime -7  -exec mv -t /destination/path {} +
```

#### How it works

- `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`

  This finds files belonging in the current directory (but not the current directory itself).
- `-mtime -7`

  This tells `find` to select only files *less than* seven days old.
- `-exec mv -t /destination/path {} +`

  This tells `find` to execute a `mv` command to move those files to `/destination/path`.

  This is efficient because `find` will replace `{} +` with many file names so that fewer `mv` processes need be created.

  Not all versions of `mv` support the `-t` option.  GNU `mv` (Linux) does.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown, what do the braces at the end mean? Also, is it possible to specify timescales other than days for     mtime?

Comment: @Eweler `find` will substitute in file names where it sees the `{}`.  In the form `{} +`, it will substitute in as many file names as fit on a command line.  (If there are too many to fit, it will run another `mv` command with the remainder as needed.)

Comment: can one explain what does the `-t` option in `mv` mean?

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair `mv -t /destination/path file1 file2` tells `mv` to move files `file1` and `file2` to `/destination/path`.  In other words, if `-t path` is specified, `mv` moves the files to `path`.  (Not all versions of `mv` support this feature.)